# Completly remove a tag from the source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I would like to remove a tag with the class of '.de'.

`$('.de').remove();` will remove it from the page but when I check the source code, then I still see the tag.

The problem that I have is, the following tag needs to be removed from the form, otherwise it will get sent and that's not what I want.

```
<input class="input_field_left de" name="friend_vorname[]" type="text" placeholder="Vorname">
```

Or maybe there is another way to not let this field get sent?!

Comment: `$('.de').remove();`  will remove all the matched elements including those in the form. How can then it be sent to server on form submission?

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do? Do you have a form with multiple languages but only want to have the chosen one to be shown? If yes, why don't you create the form dynamically, instead of hardcoding the form and trying to remove the redundant inputs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just how "view source" works in browsers. It shows you what came from the server (and usually re-queries it from the server [which may read it from cache]), **not** what is currently in the page.

To see what's currently in the page, you need to use the "Elements" or "DOM" tab in your browser's dev tools (usually opened via F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I). You can usually open it and move to a specific element by right-clicking that element on your page and choosing "Inspect element", so if you do that with your form after your `$('.de').remove();` is run, you'll see the form without the `.de` elements in it.

> The problem that I have is, the following tag needs to be removed from the form, otherwise it will get sent and that's not what I want.

No, it won't. Your `$('.de').remove();` will remove any matching elements from the page, and they will not be submitted with the form if the form is then submitted.

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right! I was only checking the "view source". It actually works great!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete a tag from source code with j Query if you want to do that try to add the tag with jQuery.(Dynamically created tags or elements only can be removed dynamically using jQuery.)