# Completely remove element / tag from DOM with JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to remove empty H1 tags from my FE environment using JS. After I remove it bots and crawlers still see these tags = they are still visible via Page Source, the DOM nodes are loaded ect..

Is there a way to **completely remove** an element from the DOM?

My html is this:

```
<a href="/link"><img src="banner.jpg" title="Title" />
  <h1 class="nivo-h1-title">
    <span></span>
  </h1>
</a>
```

Firstly i tried jQuery method:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".nivo-h1-title" ).remove();
});
```

This way the elements are removed from final HTML but still are present when you view the page via Page Source and Robots / Crowlers still see them.
I researched a lot and tried pure Javascript method using code from this link [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript) - removeChild with parentNode:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nivo-h1-title');
while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
}
```

But alas the html elements are still in the DOM = still can be seen via Page Source.

I already checked this [Completly remove a tag from the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607029/completly-remove-a-tag-from-the-source) and others, but 
**IS** there a way to do this - **completely** remove elements from source?

Comment: Javascript can remove DOM nodes, but it can't remove them from the page source (as they are served before the javascript is executed client-side). You'll probably need to handle that server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is executed *after* the initial page is served to the client. No way around that. You have to move that logic from the client-side JavaScript to a server-side language like e.g. PHP. That way it will be removed *before* the page is served.

The topic you found already had [the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34607068/2292766):

> This is just how "view source" works in browsers. It shows you what
>   came from the server (and usually re-queries it from the server [which
>   may read it from cache]), not what is currently in the page.
>
> To see what's currently in the page, you need to use the "Elements" or "DOM" tab in your browser's dev tools (usually opened via F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I). You can usually open it and move to a specific element by right-clicking that element on your page and choosing "Inspect element", so if you do that with your form after your $('.de').remove(); is run, you'll see the form without the .de elements in it.

Comment: I've come to understand it now, but then again I came across some links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942070/differences-between-detach-hide-and-remove-jquery) and others and got confused.

So generalizing = JS and jQuery (client side) methods _actually do remove_ an object from the DOM, but **after** rendering all code. 
Also, since JS method is faster - its preferred.
To **completely** remove something it has to be made server side. Was that correct?

Comment: @HristoKalaidzhiev that was perfectly correct. Well, it also is "completely" removed when you use JavaScript, but *afterwards*.